# How to rollback stored procedure that updates a table

Tags: sql, t-sql

Why doesn't this `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` statement work?

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
DECLARE @foo INT
EXECUTE [database].[dbo].[get_counter] @CounterID='inventory_records', @nextValue=@foo OUTPUT;
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
```

### Background

I'm inserting records into a customer's ERP system built on SQL Server 19. The ERP database doesn't have auto-incrementing primary keys. It instead uses a table called `counters` where each row has a `counterID` field and an integer `value` field.

To insert a new row into a table like `inventory_record`, I first need to call a stored procedure like this:

`EXECUTE get_counter @counterID='inventory_record'`

This procedure returns an `OUT` parameter called `@nextValue` which I then `INSERT` into the `inventory_record` table as its uid.

I need to `ROLLBACK` this stored procedure's behavior if my insert fails. That way the counter doesn't increase boundlessly on failed `INSERT` attempts.

#### Contents of `get_counter` stored procedure

It's dirt simple but also subject to copyright. I've summarized and truncated here. The counters are stored as sequences in the DB. So `get_counter` calls [sp_sequence_get_range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-sequence-get-range-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) after checking that the requested counter is legitimate.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE get_counter
    @strCounterID varchar(64),
    @iIncrementValue integer = 1, 
    @LastValue BIGINT = NULL OUTPUT
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON
BEGIN

DECLARE 
          @nextSeqVar SQL_VARIANT
        , @lastSeqVar SQL_VARIANT

-- code that confirms valid counter name

BEGIN TRY
    -- code that calls [sp_sequence_get_range]
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    THROW
END CATCH

RETURN(@LastValue)
END
```

### The Problem

The `inventory_record` counter **always** increments. I can't roll it back.

If I run the SQL at the top of this question from SSMS, then `SELECT value FROM counters WHERE counterID = 'inventory_record'`, the counter increments each time I execute.

I'm new to transaction handling in SQL Server. Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: Why not convert to IDENTITY data types for PKs?  Is there a ```COMMIT``` in ```get_counter```?

Comment: What does the code for `get_counter` look like?

Comment: @MartinSmith I added details about get_counter. Basically it just calls a built-in system procedure that fetches the next value from a sequence. Neither procedure uses any `COMMIT` statements.

Comment: @alexherm Since this is a client installation with a big C++ application on top of it, I can't change how data is stored in the database.

Comment: is your `insert` statement wrapped in the same `BEGIN TRAN` as the `get_counter` ?

Comment: @Squirrel It is, yes. But even apart from that, I'm trying to figure out why the SQL at the top of my question doesn't even work. It seems to me that calling `get_counter` inside a transaction and then calling `ROLLBACK` in the same transaction should reverse the affects of `get_counter`. But it doesn't. This is true whether I attempt an insert or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

re-post comments as answer for better readability.

The `get_counter` is using `Sequence Numbers` (`sp_sequence_get_range`). Please refer to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sequence-numbers/sequence-numbers?view=sql-server-ver15) on **Limitation** section.

> Sequence numbers are generated outside the scope of the current
>   transaction. They are **consumed** whether the transaction using the
>   sequence number is committed or rolled back

You may see a simple demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8fbc34db7e0fbffa2de00cd2e575e465)